# Homogeneous integral equation $\xi (t) - \int_0^{\pi} \sin(x+t) \xi (x) dx = 0$

Tags: integral-equations

I have been given the homogeneous equation:

> $$\xi (t) - \int_0^{\pi} \sin(x+t) \xi (x) dx = 0$$

and I have to show that the only solution is the trivial solution. This is the adjoint homogeneous equation of a Fredholm problem I have been given, and $\xi$ is thus a linear functional. In this case $\xi \in L^q$ ($1 \leq q < \infty$).

My initial thought was to expand $\sin(x+t)$ in the natural way, but this does not give me anything at first sight.  I also considered writing it as a product of $L^2$-bases, but I am unsure what *sequence* (ansatz) to make.

Is there a trivial way to argue that the trivial solution must be the only solution?

Comment: this cries for a fouriertransform

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. 
Could you elaborate a bit? I tried transforming the equation, but it leads me to a recursive argument.

Comment: Hint : Use sine formula, then it should give $\xi(t)=a\sin t+b\cos t$, then substitute back in the original equ.